# Multisampling with glBlitFramebuffer not working opengl es 3.0

Tags: c++, antialiasing, opengl-es-3.0, multisampling

**Overview**: Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943394/opengl-es-2-0-antialiasing-or-smoothing-on-ios-and-android-from-shared-c-code), i changed to ES 3.0, and after reading and trying for a day, i'm stuck once again in achieving Antialiasing. I'm testing this on iOS simulator.

**Issue**: My drawings are visible, but they are the same as there is no antialiasing. I have tried using ObjC's `[self.glkView setDrawableMultisample:GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X];` and the difference is notable. Meaning my multisampling isnt working at all. Is there something i'm missing?

**Resources used**: I've read [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW4)(using es3 update) as a base guide. [Kronos wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling#Allocating_a_Multisample_Render_Target) as additional guide (tho it uses `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)` which isnt present in ES3... something similar i found is the `sample coverage` and i've tried enabling that as well, but still no luck).

**Code**:

```
/*
setting up shader program code...
*/

// initializing frame buffers
glGenFramebuffers(1, &sampleFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, sampleFramebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &sampleColorRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, sampleColorRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, sampleColorRenderbuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &sampleDepthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, sampleDepthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, sampleDepthRenderbuffer);


if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    printf("Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));


// Making Draw FrameBuffer
glGenFramebuffers(1, &resolveFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, resolveFrameBuffer);


glGenRenderbuffers(1, &resolveColorRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, resolveColorRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, resolveColorRenderbuffer);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    printf("Failed to make complete framebuffer2 object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));



// Cleaning buffer steps
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, sampleFramebuffer);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

When this is done, in my drawing code, after drawing has been done i do this:

```
*use gl program*
*drawarrays*

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, sampleFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, resolveFrameBuffer);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, _Width, _Height, 0, 0, _Width, _Height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
checkGLError("glBlitFramebuffer");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was because of how i was testing my drawings. I had set the fragment shader to always give pure red color `(r:1,g:0,b:0,a:1)`. I was doing this because my android project was set up by someone else and was not fully completed when i took a copy. To avoid work on that i improvised and set color to red so i can see what is being drawn on a black background (dumb idea).

**TLDR**: Overwriting the fragment shader output made sure any antialiasing that was being done was overwritten. Setting it back to what the vertex shader was giving fixed it.